# Mule 4 : HTTP Requester : How to send multipart/form-data as POST Body for Mule REST Service Call?

Tags: multipartform-data, dataweave, rest, mule4

Scenario:

I have to make a REST Service Call from inside Mule 4 and send multipart/form-data as POST Body.

To form the multipart/form data in Dataweave I did the following:

```
%dw 2.0
output multipart/form-data 
---
{
    parts: {
        Field1: {
            headers : {
                "Content-Type": "text/plain"
            },
            content: "Value1"
        },
        Field2: {
            headers : {
                "Content-Type": "text/plain"
            },
            content: "Value2"
        },
        Field3: {
            headers : {
                "Content-Type": "text/plain"
            },
            content: "Value3"
        }
    }
}
```

And then in HTTP Request, I set the payload in HTTP Requester Body.

[image: HTTP Requester Body]

But when I make the REST API Call, I am getting the error `Missing Field1`

What can be a solution to this?

Comment: Please show the complete XML snippet (Transform, HTTP request) and the complete error message copied from the log with all details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked fine for me:

```
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message">
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output multipart/form-data 
---
{
    parts: {
        Field1: {
            headers : {
                "Content-Type": "text/plain"
            },
            content: "Value1"
        },
        Field2: {
            headers : {
                "Content-Type": "text/plain"
            },
            content: "Value2"
        },
        Field3: {
            headers : {
                "Content-Type": "text/plain"
            },
            content: "Value3"
        }
    }
}]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <http:request method="POST" doc:name="Request" config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration" path="/backend" >
        </http:request>
```

Comment: the request has no errors. actually i needed to send the parameters as url encoded form parameters and not multipart form data.